# Getting errors ydn-db on android browser

Tags: android, ydn-db

We're building an app and want to use the ydn-db to store local data. On PC browsers we don't have any issues, but on my Android phone (and iOS simulator) we get a lot of errors. Even the example/unittest page is giving a lot of errors. Like tests 1-8 are giving timeout, uncaught SQL Errors and "Expected 2 assertions, but 1 were run" errors. I'm running Android 4.0.3.

The simple todo app is working, so something is working, but ...

Anyone have any idea if there is a stable version to use?